# CSS @media(min-width) doesnt work on phone

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-deployment, web-frontend

I´m currently making a menu sidebar that should be always open when the screen width is over 568px (big enough to show the content and the menu at the same time), but openable and closable when the screen is under that width.

Code:

```
@media(min-width:568px){
  .open-slide {display:none}
  .btn-close {display:none}
  .side-nav {width:250px;margin-top:80px;}
}
```

`.open-slide` = Button to open the sidebar 
`.btn-close` = Button to close the sidebar (obviously) 
.side-nav{width:250px;margin-top:80px;} changes the standard width of the sidebar so its visible and moves its border a bit down as the "close" button isn't there any more.

When I tested this with my browser, everything worked fine. But when I tested it with my phone, the sidebar was there as if the screen was as big as a full computer screen. What is wrong there?

TL;DR: 
The code works on my pc but not on my phone, why?

Comment: Have you added the viewport? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a small jsfiddle or alternative?

Comment: @JeroenE I just figured that out , thanks!

Comment: I posted it as reply so other people are helped out aswell. Have fun coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're missing the viewport in your HTML header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Exactly, thats it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome, if you're helped out please accept the answer so people know it has an usefull answer. Have fun coding. :)

Comment: I will, but somehow I have to wait for a few minutes to accept it